# Access-control-allow-origin on aws javascript sdk getSignedUrl operation?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-javascript-sdk

Is it possible to set access-control-allow-origin on getSignedUrl operation for a S3 object? 
I have been looking out for a list of available params from the aws documentation but it's unclear.

Update: 
Suppose I have an object "test-file.jpg" in a bucket named "test-bucket". There is no CORS policy set on the bucket. 
The signed URL created by the getSignedUrl method throws 'no access-control-allow-origin header present' not allowed error in the browser.

```
var s3 = new aws.S3({'signatureVersion': 'v4'});
var options = {
    Bucket:"test-bucket",
    Key:"test-file.jpg",
    Expires:120
}
var signedUrl = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', options);
```

Is there an option to set the `access-control-allow-origin : *` in the above function call?

Comment: Calling `getSignedUrl()` doesn't make any API requests.  The signing is done locally -- wherever the SDK is running... so it isn't quite clear what you are asking.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have updated the question to make it more clear. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a way to do this.  You would need to configure CORS on the bucket.

There are some options, like `ResponseContentDisposition` that cause S3 to inject extra, customized response headers into the response when the pre-signed URL is used to fetch the object.  There is no such option for CORS.

A somewhat complex-sounding (but seemingly effective) workaround could be designed using CloudFront, Lambda@Edge, an Origin Access Identity, and CloudFront pre-signed URLs.  A Lambda response trigger would add the CORS response headers to the S3 response, which would have been authorized at S3 by the OAI after being validated by the CloudFront signed URL, and a Lambda request trigger would generate any pre-flight response the browser might require.

Comment: I guess you are right. Could you also point me to the documentation where it mentions all the available options for the getSignedUrl function call such as "ResponseContentDisposition"?

Comment: `getSignedUrl()` accepts options based on the action you want to sign, so for this, see [`getObject()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property)